# Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred when calling Firebase fetch method

Tags: swift, firebase

I have this function:

```
func fetchMyData<T: Decodable> (completion: @escaping ([T]?) -> Void) {
    
    self.db
        .collection("someCollection")
        .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            completion(nil)
            return
            }
            let result = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> T? in
                return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: T.self)
            }
            completion(result)
        }
    }
```

But when I call it:

```
self.fetchMyData() { arr in if arr != nil {
    //
}}
```

I get this error message (with a point to "self"):

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

I tried to cast a type all over the place but nothing helps so I'm not sure how to help the call to identify the type of T.

Comment: Just specify the type argument explicitly: `self.fetchMyData<TReturn>()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The protocol can not confirm by itself. You have to specify.

```
fetchMyData() { (arr : [Test]?) in
   if arr != nil {
                
   }
}
```

Here Test is the data model

```
struct Test: Decodable {
    
}
```

Comment: Perfect, it silent the error. Worth mentioning that I tried that but I've missed marking it as optinal